# state returns undefined ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a page where I can create new customer. But I stuck on one part.

I want to achieve this:

When I fill address inputs(Street, HouseNo, City, ZipCode), on form submit I want to save coordinates values in state. I'm using react-geocode for that.

At the moment I have two states:

```
const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState("");
const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState("");
```

Then I wrote this function from geocode documentation:

```
const getCoordinates = async () => {
    const coordinates = `${street} ${houseNo} ${city} ${zipCode}`;
    await Geocode.fromAddress(coordinates).then(
      (response) => {
        const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
        setLatitude(lat);
        setLongitude(lng);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  };
```

And here is my onSubmit handler:

```
const addHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!fullName || !email || !street || !houseNo || !city || !zipCode) {
      return alert("Fill Empty Inputs");
    }

    const id = customers.length + 1;
    const newCustomer = {
      id,
      fullName,
      email,
      address: {
        street,
        houseNo,
        city,
        zipCode,
        latitude,
        longitude,
      },
    };
    getCoordinates();
    customers.push(newCustomer);
    setCustomers(customers);
    setIsAdding(false);
  };
```

For some reason my latitude and longitude values are not updated. And I'm getting undefined. What I'm doing wrong?

I'll be very appreciated for any help and ideas! :)

Comment: if `lattitude` and `longitude` are `undefined`, then the response must have `undefined`. Have you set a breakpoint in the `.then` to look at the response object?

Comment: The thing is if I console.log (lat, lng) below this line - const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location; 
I get correct coordinates..

Answer (score 0):

The `latitude` / `longitude` state get updated after the network call request is fulfilled. However, the rest of the code in `addHandler` method gets executed before. That's why you are not getting the updated state values.

I have done a few tweaks here and there to handle this -

```js
const getCoordinates = async () => {
   try {
     const coordinates = `${street} ${houseNo} ${city} ${zipCode}`;
     const response = await Geocode.fromAddress(coordinates);
     const { lat, lang } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
     // returning latitude, longitude values from getCoordinates
     return ({ lat, lang });
   } catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
   }
};

const addHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!fullName || !email || !street || !houseNo || !city || !zipCode) {
      return alert("Fill Empty Inputs");
    }

    const id = customers.length + 1;
    // awaiting for getCoordinates to return latitude, longitude values
    const { lat, lang } = await getCoordinates();
    const newCustomer = {
      id,
      fullName,
      email,
      address: {
        street,
        houseNo,
        city,
        zipCode,
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: lang,
      },
    };
    customers.push(newCustomer);
    /*
    if you are using latitude, longitude values just in this function,
    then you probably don't need to store co-ordinates in a state at all.
    Otherwise -
    */
    setLatitude(lat);
    setLongitude(lang);
    setCustomers(customers);
    setIsAdding(false);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I found a way how to solve this with useEffect hook. But I'll compare that with your suggestion.

Comment: Sure thing @Get_Date